# using out of scope variables in C++11 lambda expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std, capture

I'm playing with C++11 for fun. I'm wondering why this happens:

```
//...
std::vector<P_EndPoint> agents;
P_CommunicationProtocol requestPacket;
//...
bool repeated = std::any_of(agents.begin(), agents.end(),
                    [](P_EndPoint i)->bool 
                    {return requestPacket.identity().id()==i.id();});
```

Compilation terminates with this error:

```
error: 'requestPacket' has not been declared
```

Which is declared earlier in code. I tried `::requestPacke` and it doesn't worked too.

How can I use an external scope variable inside a lambda function?

Comment: They are inside a method of a class. That's not a good title, maybe I should change it to `out of current scope`...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to [capture the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554138/819272), either by value (using the `[=]` syntax)

```
bool repeated = std::any_of(agents.begin(), agents.end(),
                    [=](P_EndPoint i)->bool                          
                    {return requestPacket.identity().id()==i.id();});
```

or by reference (using the `[&]` syntax)

```
bool repeated = std::any_of(agents.begin(), agents.end(),
                    [&](P_EndPoint i)->bool 
                    {return requestPacket.identity().id()==i.id();});
```

Note that as @aschepler points out, [global variables with static storage duration are not captured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201213/819272), only function-level variables:

```
#include <iostream>

auto const global = 0;

int main()
{
    auto const local = 0;

    auto lam1 = [](){ return global; }; // global is always seen
    auto lam2 = [&](){ return local; }; // need to capture local

    std::cout << lam1() << "\n";
    std::cout << lam2() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Lambdas never capture globals, only function-local variables.