# Merge two constant `std::set`s in declaration (not in run-time)

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, std, stdset

I am trying to elegantly declare a constant `std::set` object that would be a merger of two other constant `std::set` objects.

```
#include <set>

const std::set<int> set_one = { 1,2,3 };
const std::set<int> set_two = { 11,15 };
const std::set<int> set_all = { 1,2,3,11,15 }; // this is not very elegant, duplication
```

Declaring `set_all` object this way is not too elegant, as it duplicates information from the previous two lines. Is there a way to use `set_one` and `set_two` constants in declaring `set_all`?

Something like this:

```
const std::set<int> set_all = set_one + set_two; // this does not compile, of course!
```

1. All objects are strictly constants.
2. There are no overlapping values in both source sets, so uniqueness will not be an issue.
3. I know how to merge sets in runtime, this is not what I am looking for.
4. I am really trying to avoid resorting to macros like this:

```
#include <set>

#define SET_ONE 1, 2, 3
#define SET_TWO 11, 15

const std::set<int> set_one = { SET_ONE };
const std::set<int> set_two = { SET_TWO };
const std::set<int> set_all = { SET_ONE, SET_TWO };
```

Comment: None of your `std::set`s are created during the compile time (they are all created during runtime, because they allocate).

Comment: `std::set` uses dynamic allocation.  That means it is created at run time, well at least until possibly C++20.

Answer (score 6):

You can pack them into a lambda and call it immediately (i.e. **[IIFE](https://www.bfilipek.com/2016/11/iife-for-complex-initialization.html)**).

```
const std::set<int> set_all = [&set_one, &set_two]() {
   std::set<int> set{ set_one.cbegin(),set_one.cend() };
   set.insert(set_two.cbegin(), set_two.cend());
   return set;
}(); // ---> call the lambda!
```

However, if you have the sets in [the global scope(like *@Kevin* mentioned)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474957/why-lambda-captures-only-automatic-storage-variables), you should use the lambda which takes the two sets as arguments

```
#include <set>

using Set = std::set<int>;    // type alias
const Set set_one = { 1,2,3 };
const Set set_two = { 11,15 };

const Set set_all = [](const Set& setOne, const Set& setTwo)
{
   Set set{ setOne.cbegin(), setOne.cend() };
   set.insert(setTwo.cbegin(), setTwo.cend());
   return set;
}(set_one, set_two); // ---> call the lambda with those two sets!
```

or simply

```
const std::set<int> set_all = []()
{
   std::set<int> set{ set_one.cbegin(),set_one.cend() };
   set.insert(set_two.cbegin(), set_two.cend());
   return set;
}(); // ---> call the lambda!
```

---

> I know how to merge sets in runtime, this is not what I am looking
> for.

**No**, You can not create the [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) at compile time as it uses [dynamic allocation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer). Therefore, everything happens at run-time. Even the above lambda.

Comment: Remove the capture (`&`) if these sets are global variables (as seems to be the case in OP's code)

Comment: you should clarify that this is not "not at runtime"

Comment: @Kevin why would you assume that? That's a rare corner case. It's not worth to list every one of them and, if we don't want to list them, why mention this specific one?

Comment: @Fureeish Because of this error: `error: non-local lambda expression cannot have a capture-default` (and if you try to capture individually: `'set_one' cannot be captured because it does not have automatic storage duration`)

Comment: @Kevin imo that's saying "if you do this weird stuff, which you shouldn't have done at the first place, then the code above has to be slightly changed". I do not believe adding such corner cases to answers is beneficial in any way.

Comment: @Fureeish I wouldn't have said anything about it if the OP's code didn't have the sets as global variables. But I think it's important to mention corner cases if that's precisely what the OP is using.

Comment: @Kevin OP gave us just a portion of code and they didn't mention anything about globals. I think that should settle it.

Comment: @Fureeish OP gave us a portion of code directly below `#include <set>`, so at least in that code those variables *are* global. Considering these sets are also `const`, I don't see a reason to dismiss the idea that OP might *actually* be using globals.

Comment: Why add unused parameters to the lambda? Removing the captures should be enough.