# How to access a global variable in a lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda, global-variables, gcc-warning

Which of the below two lambda functions is correct?

```
#include <cstdlib>


extern constinit int exit_code { };

int main( )
{
    auto lambda_1 { [ &exit_code ]( ) noexcept
                    {
                        exit_code = EXIT_FAILURE;
                    } };

    auto lambda_2 { [ ]( ) noexcept
                    {
                        exit_code = EXIT_FAILURE;
                    } };

    lambda_1( );
    lambda_2( );

    return exit_code;
}
```

GCC warns about `&exit_code`:

```
warning: capture of variable 'exit_code' with non-automatic storage duration
```

Clang shows an error about it:

```
error: 'exit_code' cannot be captured because it does not have automatic storage duration
```

If the above code is not correct (for instance *ill-formed*), then what is the correct way of making the global variable accessible to a lambda? Is `lambda_2` legal? If it's not then why doesn't GCC also warn about the usage of the global variable in `lambda_2`? How does it access it without even *capturing* it?

If none is correct, then how should the above code be designed?

Comment: why should it need to be captured?

Comment: global variables are *global*, i.e. accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to capture non-local variables. From [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> A lambda expression can use a variable without capturing it if the variable
>
> - **is a non-local variable** or has static or thread local storage duration (in which case the variable cannot be captured), or

And since `exit_code` is a **global variable**, it can be used withing the lambda's body, without capturing it.

See [Why lambda captures only automatic storage variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474957/why-lambda-captures-only-automatic-storage-variables)